# Django- How to Exclude parent class' fields

Tags: python, django

I have a requirement where I want to exclude all parent fields, just include fields explicitly defined in child.

For brevity, here's my django code:

```
#app2 models.py
class EmployeeExtended(app1.Employee):
    boss = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

#app1 admin.py
class EmployeeExtendedInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = app2.EmployeeExtended
    fields = ['boss']

class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EmployeeExtendedInline]
```

This code is working. If I dont give `fields`, it will include all parent fields also. But I dont want to explicitly write `fields=['boss']`. Rather I want something like:

```
for field in EmployeeExtendedOnly_Not_In_Its_Parent:
    fields.append(field)
```

Please suggest code for `EmployeeExtendedOnly_Not_In_Its_Parent`

Comment: is app1.Employee an abstract model or a real model?

Comment: Its a real model. Has its own table in database. EmployeeExtended has an implicit fk to Employee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to get away with

```
fields = [f.name for f in app1.EmployeeExtended._meta._fields() if f not in app1.Employee._meta._fields()]
```

But, to be honest, this is ugly and I cannot see why you extended Employee. Extending make a OneToOneKey between the two models. It seems what you need is a ForeignKey.

Comment: +1, This intersection of fields will help. Still I want to know if this information is directly available in _meta somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I excluded all of the base class / model from my derived classes / models when they are shown in the admin user interface in Django. Here is my Base class:

```
class BaseLTI(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    def get_excluded_field_names():
        return [f.name for f in BaseLTI._meta.fields]
```

Here is one of my derived classes:

```
class Subject(BaseLTI):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=42, null=False)
    ...
```

Then in my `admin.py` file, I did the following:

```
from .models import BaseLTI, Subject

class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = BaseLTI.get_excluded_field_names();
admin.site.register(Subject, SubjectAdmin)
```

This will hide all the fields from the base class in the Django Admin UI.  I like this because it feels most flexible.  For example in `BaseLTI` I could tweak the list of fields and let a few show if I wanted.  Also, when I register each of the derived classes in `admin.py`, I could tweak the returned exclude list a bit.